# How to save ID of selected value of dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I am new to webmatrix and I have a dropdown list that selects Areas from a table using this code:

```
<select>
@foreach(var row in SelectArea){
    <option> @row.Areas</option>
 }
 </Select>
```

In the table, each area has a unique ID. I want to save the ID of the selected area to insert it together with other information into another table in the DB. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this code is inside an HTML `<form>` that gets submitted to your server you could add a `value` attribute to your options. Also give a name to your dropdown so that later you aare able to retrieve the selected value:

```
<select name="selectedRow">
@foreach(var row in SelectArea) {
    <option value="@row.Id">@row.Areas</option>
}
</select>
```

Now when the form is submitted, the value of the selected option will be sent to the server. Then when the form is submitted you will be able to retrieve the selected id from the request:

```
var id = Request["selectedRow"];
...
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve the problem you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Don't you love it when you go to the trouble of helping someone and once they have their answer they no longer care enough to make a simple click or two? Oh well, he's obviously new, maybe he just doesn't know. +1 From me, at least.

Comment: Oh Yah. I am new to this forum. So apologies, I have ticked the answer now.